# How to use job specific email recipient address in Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I try to find a way to set the email recipient at the start of a Spring Batch Job. The problem is that I have to change the behavior of an existing job, which initialize it's email recipient (mail-to) at the beginning of the Spring Boot initialization.

```
<int-mail:header-enricher input-channel="expressionsInput" default-overwrite="false">
    <int-mail:to expression="payload.to"/>
    <int-mail:cc expression="payload.cc"/>
    <int-mail:bcc expression="payload.bcc"/>
    <int-mail:from expression="payload.from"/>
    <int-mail:reply-to expression="payload.replyTo"/>
    <int-mail:subject expression="payload.subject" overwrite="true"/>
</int-mail:header-enricher>
```

How is it possible to specify a custom email address at for every new job?

Comment: Please, provide more info how do you use that config. Spring Batch has `job` scope, so you can store job-specific config there and send a message to that `<int-mail:header-enricher>`

Answer (score 0):

`<int-mail:to expression="payload.to"/>`

It's already initialized to a variable expression; there must be some field `to` on the message payload, and a getter `getTo()`.

So, all you need to do is change the value that is set in the payload.

You can change this expression to calculate those header values any way you want.